# Elisp backtrace print garbage messages

Tags: backtrace, bytecode

I'm using emacs 25.2 on osx 10.12 and following elisp intro to produce some error message intentionally.

```
(This is a list)
```

After I run `C-x C-e` on this line. A backtrace buffer appeared as supposed but with garbage error messages:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function This)
  (This is a list)
  eval((This is a list) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  #[257 "\204�\303!\207 \303!\n)B\211A  =\204�\211A\211@\207" [eval-expression-debug-on-error elisp--eval-last-sexp-fake-value debug-on-error elisp--eval-last-sexp] 4 2273792 "P"](nil)
  ad-Advice-eval-last-sexp(#[257 "\204�\303!\207    \303!\n)B\211A  =\204�\211A\211@\207" [eval-expression-debug-on-error elisp--eval-last-sexp-fake-value debug-on-error elisp--eval-last-sexp] 4 2273792 "P"] nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-eval-last-sexp #[257 "\204�\303!\207  \303!\n)B\211A  =\204�\211A\211@\207" [eval-expression-debug-on-error elisp--eval-last-sexp-fake-value debug-on-error elisp--eval-last-sexp] 4 2273792 "P"] nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

This seems like an encoding problem but I have no idea what to do with this. I'm more than happy to provide further information.

Comment: It's bytecode. There are emacs-devel@gnu.org discussions about this problem, as well as bug reports about it ([eg 6991](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6991))and discussions of how to fix it. If you reevaluate the definition of a Lisp function and don't byte-compile it, you won't see its bytecode in the backtrace.

Comment: Interestingly, in the multiple discussions of this problem/annoyance, I don't recall anyone pointing out that it can also confuse users into thinking that perhaps they have a problem with character encoding and thus seeking a solution for that (non-problem). Yet another reason to fix this.

Comment: @Drew tks for your information. Guess you met a completely newbie here lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks perfectly "normal" to me: the `\NNN` you see are bytes in the bytecode of the functions that have been used to run your code.

It's somewhat annoying to see them in the backtrace, indeed, so after a few decades of living with it, Emacs-26 finally changed to provide a prettier representation.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the change? I've considered adding an option to print it as "<bytecode>" instead, similar to what Xemacs does.

Comment: There's a new `cl-print` library in Emacs-26, which prints structs and bytecode functions in a more human-readable way.  AFAICT it hasn't yet been hooked to the debug.el code (that handles the `*Backtrace*` debugger), but it's a very simple change.

Comment: Apparently [@npostavs expects to merge that code into the development version next week](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6991#186). Is it a coincidence that this question was posted here today, and this change was made just after that? Perhaps it was a timely reminder. Hooray for users! ;-)